# Converting SpriteSheet Metadata .txt to .yaml

Tags: guava, kotlin, yaml

For practice I decided that I wanted to write an animation class for SpriteSheets. The problem is that a single Sprite can have different widths depending on the action they are drawn to act. A tool called [Sprite Sheet Packer](http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/) creates a Map file documenting the index and bounds of each sprite. This file looks a little like this:

```
0 = 157 184 123 189
1 = 187 0 177 183
2 = 402 181 105 189
3 = 495 0 111 180
4 = 710 0 102 171

walking = 1 2 3 4
```

Note that the `walking = 1 2 3 4` is actually **not** part of the map file, but I want to add some extra information, such as which animation is comprised of which frames. This I convert into the following yaml:

```
Frames:
- Index: 0
  Bounds: [157, 184, 123, 189]
- Index: 1
  Bounds: [187, 0, 177, 183]
- Index: 2
  Bounds: [402, 181, 105, 189]
- Index: 3
  Bounds: [495, 0, 111, 180]
- Index: 4
  Bounds: [710, 0, 102, 171]
Animations:
- Name: walking
  Frames: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is my code (which uses Guava):

```
data class TextParseException(message: String = "", cause: Throwable? = null): RuntimeException(message, cause)

/**
 * <h2>Converts a Metadata .txt file into a .yaml file.</h2>
 *
 * <b>Format of a metadata text file:</b>
 * <pre>
 *      <index>: <x> <y> <width> <height>
 *      ...
 *
 *      <name>: <frame1> <frame2> ... <frameN>
 *      ...
 * </pre>
 *
 * <p>Be aware that a blank line (between ... and <name>) is the separator between
 * frame and animation entries. Trailing newspaces are ok, but any others will break
 * the parsing.</p>
 *
 * <b>Output format:</b>
 * <pre>
 *      Frames:
 *        - Index: <index>
 *          Bounds: [<x>, <y>, <width>, <height>]
 *        ...
 *      Animations:
 *        - Name: <name<
 *          Frames: [<frame1>, <frame2>, ..., <frameN>
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param metadata path to metadata file for parsing
 * @returns formatted .yaml string of metadata contents
 * @throws TextParseException if an error occurs parsing a frame or animation entry
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the metadata file does not exist
 * @throws IOException if the file could not be accessed or read
 */
fun convertToYaml(metadata: Path): String {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(Files.exists(metadata),
                                "The file ${metadata.getFileName()} does not exist")

    val lines = Files.readAllLines(metadata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).map { it.trim() }
    if (lines.all { it.isEmpty() })
        return ""

    val yamlFrameEntries = gatherRawFrameEntries(lines)
                            .map(::split)
                            .map(::toFrameEntry)
                            .sortBy { it.index }
                            .map(::createYamlFrameEntry)

    val yamlAnimationEntries = gatherRawAnimationEntries(lines)
                                .map(::split)
                                .map(::toAnimationEntry)
                                .map(::createYamlAnimationEntry)

    return buildCompleteYaml(yamlFrameEntries, yamlAnimationEntries)
}

private fun gatherRawFrameEntries(lines: List<String>): List<String> {
    return lines.takeWhile { it.isNotEmpty() }
}

private fun gatherRawAnimationEntries(lines: List<String>): List<String> {
    return lines.dropWhile { it.isNotEmpty() }.drop(1).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
}

private fun split(line: String): List<String> {
    val normalizedEntry = line.replace("=", " ")
    val parts = Splitter.on(' ')!!
                        .trimResults()!!
                        .omitEmptyStrings()!!
                        .split(normalizedEntry)!!

    return parts.toList()
}

private data class FrameEntry(val index: Int, val bounds: List<Int>)
private data class AnimationEntry(val name: String, val frames: List<Int>)

private fun toFrameEntry(entryPieces: List<String>): FrameEntry {
    try {
        val frameIndex  = entryPieces.first!!
        val frameBounds = entryPieces.drop(1).map { it.toInt() }

        return FrameEntry(frameIndex.toInt(), frameBounds)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw TextParseException("Could not parse a Frame entry.", e)
    }
}

private fun toAnimationEntry(entryPieces: List<String>): AnimationEntry {
    try {
        val animationName   = entryPieces.first!!
        val animationFrames = entryPieces.drop(1).map { it.toInt() }

        return AnimationEntry(animationName, animationFrames)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw TextParseException("Could not parse an Animation entry.", e)
    }
}

private fun createYamlFrameEntry(frameEntry: FrameEntry): String {
    val yamlFrameEntryBuilder = StringBuilder()

    yamlFrameEntryBuilder.append("  - Index: ${frameEntry.index}\n")
    yamlFrameEntryBuilder.append("    Bounds: [")
    yamlFrameEntryBuilder.append("${Joiner.on(", ")!!.join(frameEntry.bounds)}]\n")

    return yamlFrameEntryBuilder.toString()
}

private fun createYamlAnimationEntry(animationEntry: AnimationEntry): String {
    val yamlFrameEntryBuilder = StringBuilder()

    yamlFrameEntryBuilder.append("  - Name: ${animationEntry.name}\n")
    yamlFrameEntryBuilder.append("    Frames: [")
    yamlFrameEntryBuilder.append("${Joiner.on(", ")!!.join(animationEntry.frames)}]\n")

    return yamlFrameEntryBuilder.toString()
}

private fun buildCompleteYaml(yamlFrameEntries: List<String>,
                              yamlAnimationEntries: List<String>): String {
    val completeYamlBuilder = StringBuilder()

    appendYamlEntries(completeYamlBuilder, "Frames:", yamlFrameEntries)
    if (yamlAnimationEntries.isNotEmpty())
        appendYamlEntries(completeYamlBuilder, "Animations:", yamlAnimationEntries)

    return completeYamlBuilder.toString()
}

private fun appendYamlEntries(builder: StringBuilder,
                              sectionName: String,
                              entries: List<String>) {
    builder.append("${sectionName}\n")
    entries.forEach { builder.append(it) }
}
```

These are my tests:

```
class ConverterSpec: Spek() {{
    given("A .txt -> .yaml converter") {
        on("loading a non-existent file") {
            it("throws an IllegalArgumentException") {
                failsWith(javaClass<IllegalArgumentException>()) {
                    convertToYaml(Paths.get("Missing.txt")!!)
                }
            }
        }

        on("loading an empty file") {
            val emptyFileUrl = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/Empty.txt")!!

            it("produces empty yaml") {
                val output = convertToYaml(Paths.get(emptyFileUrl.toURI())!!)

                assertTrue(output.isEmpty(),
                           "YAML output not empty, but:  $output")
            }
        }

        on("loading file with on frame entry") {
            val frameFileUrl = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/Frame.txt")!!

            it("produces corresponding yaml for frame") {
                val expected = "Frames:\n" +
                               "  - Index: 0\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [157, 184, 123, 189]\n"

                val output = convertToYaml(Paths.get(frameFileUrl.toURI())!!)

                assertEquals(expected, output,
                             "The YAML did not conform to the expected output.")
            }
        }

        on("loading file with multiple frame entries") {
            val framesFileUrl = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/Frames.txt")!!

            it("produces corresponding yaml for all frames") {
                val expected = "Frames:\n" +
                               "  - Index: 0\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [157, 184, 123, 189]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 1\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [187, 0, 177, 183]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 2\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [402, 181, 105, 189]\n"

                val output = convertToYaml(Paths.get(framesFileUrl.toURI())!!)

                assertEquals(expected, output,
                             "The YAML did not conform to the expected output.")
            }
        }

        on("loading file with frames and animations") {
            val frameAnimationFileUrl = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/FrameAnimation.txt")!!

            it("produces corresponding yaml incorporating an animation name and number of frames") {
                val expected = "Frames:\n" +
                               "  - Index: 0\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [157, 184, 123, 189]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 1\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [187, 0, 177, 183]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 2\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [402, 181, 105, 189]\n" +
                               "Animations:\n" +
                               "  - Name: Walking\n" +
                               "    Frames: [0, 1, 2]\n"

                val output = convertToYaml(Paths.get(frameAnimationFileUrl.toURI())!!)

                assertEquals(expected, output,
                             "The YAML did not conform to the expected output.\nPerhaps the Animations section is malformed?")
            }
        }

        on("loading file with no frames but animations") {
            val onlyAnimationFileUrl = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/OnlyAnimation.txt")!!

            it("throws a TextParseException") {
                failsWith(javaClass<TextParseException>()) {
                    convertToYaml(Paths.get(onlyAnimationFileUrl.toURI())!!)
                }
            }
        }

        on("loading file with trailing newlines") {
            val trailingNewlines = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/TrailingNewlines.txt")!!

            it("loads normally and ignores trailing newlines") {
                val expected = "Frames:\n" +
                               "  - Index: 0\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [157, 184, 123, 189]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 1\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [187, 0, 177, 183]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 2\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [402, 181, 105, 189]\n" +
                               "Animations:\n" +
                               "  - Name: Walking\n" +
                               "    Frames: [0, 1, 2]\n"

                val output = convertToYaml(Paths.get(trailingNewlines.toURI())!!)

                assertEquals(expected, output)
            }
        }

        on("Loading a file with unnatural ordering") {
            val unnaturalOrdering = javaClass<ConverterSpec>().getClassLoader()!!.getResource("converter/UnsortedFrames.txt")!!

            it("loads and sorts frames into natural order") {
                val expected = "Frames:\n" +
                               "  - Index: 0\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [157, 184, 123, 189]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 1\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [187, 0, 177, 183]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 2\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [402, 181, 105, 189]\n" +
                               "  - Index: 10\n" +
                               "    Bounds: [187, 0, 177, 183]\n"

                val output = convertToYaml(Paths.get(unnaturalOrdering.toURI())!!)

                assertEquals(expected, output)
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: If you're using Google Guava, please state so and add the tag [tag:guava].